# How to structure data model for a correct deserialisation?

Tags: android, rest, gson, retrofit

I am using Retrofit 2.0 to make call to currency conversion API.
I am calling:

```
https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/convert?q=USD_PLN
```

To receive this response:

```
{
  "query": {
    "count": 1
  },
  "results": {
    "USD_PLN": {
      "id": "USD_PLN",
      "val": 3.763304,
      "to": "PLN",
      "fr": "USD"
    }
  }
}
```

Now I am trying to build data model so that Gson can correctly deserialise this response. I have `ResponseWrapper.class`

```
public class ResponseWrapper {

    private Query query;
    private ConversionPair results;

}
```

`Query.class`

```
public class Query {
    private int count;
}
```

`ConversionPair.class`

```
public class ConversionPair {
    private String id;
    private Currency from;
    private Currency to;
    private float value;
}
```

What should I do about `USD_PLN` object that is in the response body? I want to be able to make different calls with different pairs. I obviously I will not create separate class for every possible pair? What is the proper way of dealing with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JsonElement as results type: `JsonElement results;` and manually convert it to a Map:

```
final Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, ConversionPair>>(){}.getType();
final Map<String, ConversionPair> objects = new Gson().fromJson(results, type);
```

Now you can loop through objects

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to ask API team to change the field and make that generic

```
 {  
   "query":{  
      "count":1
   },
   "results":{  
      "currency":{  // Currency should be fixed
         "id":"USD_PLN",
         "val":3.763304,
         "to":"PLN",
         "fr":"USD"
      }
   }
}
```

Use [JsonToPojoConverter](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

```
public class Example {

    @SerializedName("query")

    private Query query;
    @SerializedName("results")

    private Results results;

    public Query getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(Query query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public Results getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(Results results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

}


public class Query {

    @SerializedName("count")

    private Integer count;

    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Integer count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

}


public class Results {

    @SerializedName("USD_PLN")

    private USDPLN uSDPLN;

    public USDPLN getUSDPLN() {
        return uSDPLN;
    }

    public void setUSDPLN(USDPLN uSDPLN) {
        this.uSDPLN = uSDPLN;
    }

}

public class USDPLN {

    @SerializedName("id")

    private String id;
    @SerializedName("val")

    private Double val;
    @SerializedName("to")

    private String to;
    @SerializedName("fr")

    private String fr;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Double getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(Double val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getFr() {
        return fr;
    }

    public void setFr(String fr) {
        this.fr = fr;
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not was I was asking about. USD_PLN is an object that is specific fot this currency pair. How do I deal with having more generic object?

Comment: I think if API team change this field USD_PLN to Currency or something meaning full name and should always value come under this. then you don't need to manual conversion. Have modified answer post accordingly. Here I just want to avoid manual conversion.